# What are the risks of staking at a pool?

Tags: staking

Imagine the pool operator goes offline due to technical reasons, what are the risks for investors staking at that pool?

Answer (score 3):

None, if the pool goes offline then you just can't stake to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have delegated your funds to the staking pool, you have nothing to worry about, even if this pool went offline. Staking is 100% safe. A delegation to a staking pool is a separate action as opposed to transferring your funds.